# Collapsible Master Detail preferably using ListView

Tags: android, jquery, listview

I need to show Product list (perhaps some kind of ListView) and be able to display product details (could be more than 3/4 items and a place order button) when a product is clicked.

I have seen similar Accordion behavior but the expandable items are just single list items in my case I need to show multiple attributes of the product.

One way is to build a string combining all product attributes i need to display and bind to list. What are my other options?

I am relatively new to Android.

Note: I don't have enough reputation to upload an image/mockup.